# Flutter close drawer on back button press in bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer, drawer, flutter-bottomnavigation

I'm building a flutter app with persistent bottom navigation bar that contains a menu button.
[image]

The menu is supposed to open a drawer from any screen and trough the back button it should close it.
For that I'm using a scaffold including the bottom navigation widget and also the drawer.
This works fine for all screens that are directly accessible trough the bottom navigation bar.

The problem arises if I navigate (I'm using auto_route for routing) to another sub page.
In the sub page it seems that it is not possible to close the drawer.

In the sub page I dont provide a Scaffold since I would have nested scaffolds.

I'm using the **WillPopScope** and onPop looks like this:

```
if (Scaffold.of(context).isEndDrawerOpen) {
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Unfortunately this just pops the sub page while the drawer stays open.

One solution would be to pass a closing function to every child screen (or something like a global key for the global scaffold) but I would appreciate a more elegant solution

Do you have any idea how I can fix that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm curious, is `Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes it does work but I want to close the drawer. The problem is, that Navigator.of(context).pop() pops the screen instead of the drawer.